# Turkish transfer visa for an Egyptian citizen

Tags: visas, transit, istanbul, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian citizen and I am planning a flight from Kazan (Tatarstan) via Istanbul (transfer at the airport 5 hours) to Hurghada, do I need to apply for a Turkish visa for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are self-connecting in Istanbul you will need a visa. Transit without a visa is permitted subject to the following conditions:

From [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb2.com/integration/external?ref=d975cfc59f5c0abd06d16e872198110b&clear=true)

> Passengers transiting through Ankara (ESB), Antalya (AYT), Istanbul: Metropolitan Area (IST) and Sabiha Gokcen (SAW), or Izmir (ADB) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

> TWOV in Antalya (AYT) does not apply when transiting between terminals 1 and 2.